# Disabling sql services while performing maintenance on SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster

Tags: sql-server, clustering

Our storage team is performing updates on an MPIO driver for our SQL Server 2008 R2 cluster.  They suggested disabling the sql server service on the node they are doing the update on - will disabling the sql server service interfere with the configuration of the cluster or have no impact?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the service will not impact the cluster configuration. I would disable the node in possible owners as well to make sure that the server will not try to failover.

Answer (score 0):

I would pause the node instead. This will prevent any role from starting on the node.